# How do I get the nth file of a directory by alphabetical order?

Tags: c#, file, indexing, directory

Well I haven't seen this before but is there a special method that will open the *nth* file in a directory?

Although I don't really have much code to show but I know that this can get my the size of the directory:

```
int fileCount = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\user\Collection").Length;
```

Is there a such thing as "file index"? I prefer not to convert it to an array as it has over 900 files inside.

EX: I want the 3rd file of the directory. It is named "test.txt".

Comment: What do you mean by the nth file of a directory?  nth alphabetically? by created date? modified date? file size?

Comment: Sorry I meant by alphabetical order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Directory.GetFiles` [returns an array of full paths](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Simply sort it and access it via index.

```
var files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\user\Collection").OrderBy(name => name).ToArray();
File.ReadAllText(files[index]); <-- index is your N
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Directory.EnumerateFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383458%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
var result = Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"C:\Users\user\Collection")
                      .OrderBy(x => x)
                      .Skip(2)
                      .First();
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

The advantage of EnumerateFile is that you don't need to have the full list of files in memory, but you could start immediately to apply the required logic